# MySQL - dont show any row from ID use

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I just need to show the values that don't use the specifically ID.
I have two table

table 1

```
id_xx
1
2
3
4
5
```

table 2

```
id | id_xx
3  |  3
4  |  3
4  |  1
```

I need this results for example. I say which results from ID i need

i need this result where id=3

```
id_xx
1
2
4
5
```

or where id=4

```
id_xx
2
4
5
```

or where id=1

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `LEFT JOIN` `table1` with `table2` and apply the filter in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`, and then filter on unmatched records:

```
SELECT t1.id_xx
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id_xx = t1.id_xx AND t2.id = ?
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

You can replace the question mark with the `id` that you need to check.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4pLJjXX8wo6HhWdXnxqVyz/0)**:

Given `t2.id = 3`:

```
| id_xx |
| ----- |
| 1     |
| 2     |
| 4     |
| 5     |
```

Given `t2.id = 4`:

```
| id_xx |
| ----- |
| 2     |
| 4     |
| 5     |
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using a [Correlated Subquery with `NOT EXISTS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```sql
SELECT t1.id_xx
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM table2 AS t2 
                  WHERE t2.id = ?   -- your input id here
                    AND t2.id_xx = t1.id_xx)
```

If you have large table(s), and are worried about performance of these queries, then you *may* define the following index:

- For the correlated subquery, define composite index `(id, id_xx)` on `table2`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD INDEX(id, id_xx);
```

Assuming that `id_xx` is already a Primary Key in the table1. So, you don't need to define any index there. If not, then you can define an index on it.

Comment: This seems to produce the expected results as well, why was it downvoted?

Comment: @GMB thanks.. never mind.. if someone gets a sadistic pleasure, let him/her be :-)